# Timer Interrupt In Non-Preemptive Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How are Timer Interrupt handled in Non-Preemptive Kernel?
Ex some question:

1. In uniprocessor+Non-Preemptive Kernel.
   Suppose code is running in Kernel Mode,like some system call/devicedriver is executing. How are timer interrupts handled in this case.
   Are timer interrupts disabled here? Are timer interrupts masked?

   If yes, then in this setting code will it continue to run until it finishes OR call yield() voluntarily?.

   If No,  then does the scheduler which runs on timer interrupt schedules the same process again to avoid race condition?

---

1. Is Non-preemptive Same as Interrupt Disabling(while in Kernel Code*)?

   If yes, in which case?

   If No,  in which case?

Comment: Did you look inside the Linux kernel source code? Did you ask on http://kernelnewbies.org/ ?

Comment: Nope, If will ask on Kernelnewbies.org. Also can you please direct me to wherein the kernel source code will I get more info on my questions.